# Wix setup doesn't stop service on uninstall

Tags: .net, installation, wix, windows-services

I've a windows .Net 7 application, which use Wix to create a setup.
Here is how our service is defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <?include ..\Common.wxi?>

        <DirectoryRef Id="BIN">
            <Component Id="MyNameSpace_MyService" Guid="72044696-3E92-4928-BC6D-5A9C5FBB924A" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
                <File Id="MyNameSpaceMyService.exe"
                      Name="MyNameSpaceMyService.exe"
                      KeyPath="yes"
                      Vital="no"
                      Compressed="default"
                      DiskId="1"
                      Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyNameSpaceMyService.exe" />
                <ServiceControl Id="Uninstall"
                    Name="MyProductMyService"
                    Stop="both"
                    Remove="uninstall" />
                <ServiceInstall Id="NewServiceInstall2"
                    Name="MyProductMyService"
                    DisplayName="MyProduct Host Service"
                    Type="ownProcess"
                    Interactive="no"
                    Start="auto"
                    ErrorControl="normal"
                    Vital="no" />

            </Component>
            <Component Id="MyNameSpace_MyService_Files" Guid="4DC25232-0B8D-4C16-ABC9-5BD5B45D0358" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
                <File Id="MyNameSpaceMyService.dll" Name="MyNameSpaceMyService.dll" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyNameSpaceMyService.dll" />
                <File Id="MyNameSpaceMyService.deps.json" Name="MyNameSpaceMyService.deps.json" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyNameSpaceMyService.deps.json" />
                <File Id="MyNameSpaceMyService.dll.config" Name="MyNameSpaceMyService.dll.config" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyNameSpaceMyService.dll.config" />
                <File Id="MyNameSpaceMyService.runtimeconfig.json" Name="MyNameSpaceMyService.runtimeconfig.json" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyNameSpaceMyService.runtimeconfig.json" />
                <File Id="MyNameSpaceMyServiceCore.dll" Name="MyNameSpaceMyServiceCore.dll" Vital="no" Compressed="default" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.DirDotfuscated)\MyNameSpaceMyServiceCore.dll" />
            </Component>

        </DirectoryRef>

    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The service is started by a custom action, in order to display a message if the port used by the service is already used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?include ..\SetupWix\Common.wxi?>
    <Product Id="B924E877-F881-4942-BE5F-A2C9702BAA52"
             Codepage="1252"
             Language="1033"
             Manufacturer="$(var.MANUFACTURER)"
             Name="Start Vibrosight Host Service"
             UpgradeCode="c02eb69e-6451-4d51-be2d-be3502aa961c"
             Version="$(var.ProductVersion)">
      <Package Compressed="yes"
               InstallScope="perMachine"
               InstallPrivileges="elevated"
               Comments="http://www.MeggittSA.com"
               Description="Start Host Service"
               InstallerVersion="200"
               Keywords="Installer,MSI,Database"
               Languages="1033"
               Manufacturer="[ProductManufacturer]"/>

      <!--This will prevent this package from being visible on the Add/Remove Programs feature-->
      <Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1" />

      <Binary Id="CustomActionsDLL" SourceFile="..\CustomActions\bin\CustomActions.CA.dll"/>
      <CustomAction Id="CA_TryStartHostService" BinaryKey="CustomActionsDLL" DllEntry="TryStartHostService" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>

      <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CA_TryStartHostService" After="InstallInitialize">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>

      <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Starting Host Service" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="SetupService" />
      </Feature>
      <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Data1.cab" DiskPrompt="1" EmbedCab="yes" VolumeLabel="DISK1" CompressionLevel="none" />
      <Property Id="DiskPrompt" Value="[1]" />
      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="StartingHostService" >
          <Component Id="SetupService" Guid="7AA67E85-DFB9-4B43-A4FC-FFCE25AAE985" Win64="yes">
            <RemoveFolder On="both" Id="RemoveInstallDir64"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

With the custom action being:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult TryStartMyService(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ServiceController serviceController  = GetHostServiceController())
            {
                if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running 
                    || serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
                {
                    return ActionResult.Success;
                }

                if (!CheckIfPortIsAvailable(session, MY_SERVICE_PORT_NUMBER))
                {
                    Record record = new Record
                    {
                        FormatString =
                            $"WARNING: The Service cannot be started because the port {MY_SERVICE_PORT_NUMBER} is already in use. Please close the application using this port and restart the service manually."
                    };
                    session.Message(InstallMessage.Warning, record);
                }

                serviceController.Start();
                try
                {
                    serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    Record record = new Record
                    {
                        FormatString = "ERROR: The Service failed to start whithin the specified timeout.\n\nPlease try to restart this service manually."
                    };
                    session.Message(InstallMessage.Warning, record);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Record record = new Record
            {
                FormatString = $"ERROR: The Service failed to start with error:\n{ex.Message}.\n\nPlease try to restart this service manually."
            };
            session.Message(InstallMessage.Warning, record);
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

The service is installed properly, but when I do uninstall the app, the service isn't stopped, until it crashes(like 5min after the uninstallation) because some DLL are missing(due to uninstall).

Then I've some left-over files in my Program Files folder.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?